# Bootstrap 3 IE8 navigation jump

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've noticed a small issue in that when the page loads, using IE8, the main top navigation, using Bootstrap 3.1.1, starts off collapsed and then when the page has finished loading the main top navigation resizes to full width, i.e. normal size. This creates a bit of a jump on the page, which isn't ideal. It is particularly apparent on slow connections and only appears to occur in IE8. Any ideas or anyway to smooth it out somehow?

I'm including all the usual bits:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<script src="~/scripts/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't add this as a comment because I don't have enough rep...

What is the order you are laying out your conditional comments? You should be loading your CSS and the rest of the script before you do the IE8 conditionals.

If that's all correct, then Paul Spranger's solution might work for you (ref: http://www.paulsprangers.com/2011/09/remove-respond-js-screen-flicker/). Seems like it might be directly related to respond.js.

Comment: Thanks Aibrean, thats looks exactly like my issue!!